# Is there an easier way to create this form without having to put in the options for all day all year and all months?

Tags: javascript, html, vuejs3

[image: forms]

I am creating this form, but I really don't want to put in the options of for 31 days and 12 months and humph year?.

Also I want the option if I choose February it makes the dates limit to 28 and additionally I want to save this to a database as how an actual data picker would save the information?

Is there an horizontal  date picker option.. See my code below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('form').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var month = $('#month').val();
    var day = $('#day').val();
    var year = $('#year').val();

    // Perform any further processing or validation here

    // Example: Log the selected birthday
    console.log("Selected birthday: " + month + "/" + day + "/" + year);
  });
});
```

```html
<div>
  <form>
    <label for="month">Month:</label>
    <select id="month" name="month">
      <option value="">Select Month</option>
      <option value="01">January</option>
      <option value="02">February</option>
      <!-- Add options for the rest of the months -->
    </select>
    <label for="day">Day:</label>
    <select id="day" name="day">
      <option value="">Select Day</option>
      <option value="">1</option>
      <!-- Add options for the days, 1 to 31 -->
    </select>
    <label for="year">Year:</label>
    <select id="year" name="year">
      <option value="">Select Year</option>
      <!-- Add options for the years, such as from 1900 to the current year -->
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You could use a [date input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date).

Comment: You can use JavaScript to generate all the options in a loop.

Comment: I am running from the date input, I want it to be a drop down for each field (Month, Day, year)

Comment: @Barmar how do i do that?

Comment: `for (let day = 1; day <= 31; day++) { code that adds an <option> for that day }`

Comment: why make 3 separate inputs when you could use an input date?

Comment: @ChrisG looks better and fits the design of my project. Just don't know how to pull it off that is all..

Comment: @Barmar can you tell me what I am missing what this one not working?

https://jsfiddle.net/Scatter/5u6cx9pj/2/

Comment: You put `<script>` in the JavaScript box. You shouldn't do that, it should just contain the JavaScript code, jsfiddle puts it in the tag.

Comment: thanks @Barmar that works.. But when i select February I want 28 days etc? and how i consol log this to be similar to a date you pick from a date picker?

Comment: In that case you need to use cascading menus. Use a `change` event listener for the Month dropdown and fill in the Day dropdown.

Comment: @Barmar think i finally got it.. thanks man.. https://jsfiddle.net/Scatter/5u6cx9pj/10/